# Understanding J From

Tags: j

In J:

```
a =: 2 3 $ 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Gives:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Which is a `2 3` shaped array.

If I do:

```
0 1 { a
```

I (noting that `0 1` is a `2` shaped list) expected to have back:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

But got the following instead:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Reading the documentation I was expecting the shape of the index to kinda govern the shape of the answer.

Can someone clarify what I am missing here?

Comment: Try `0 0 1 0 { a`, then try `0 0 1 0 { 'abcde'`. I think it will clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Higher-dimensional arrays may help make this clear. An array with `n` dimensions has *items* with `n-1` dimensions. When you select an *item* from (`{`) a three-dimensional array, your result is a two-dimensional array:

```
   1 { i. 5 3 4
12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23
```

When you select multiple *items* from an array, the *items* are assembled into a new array, using each *atom* of `x` to select a *item* of `y`. This might be where you picked up the idea that the shape of `x` affects the shape of the result.

```
   2 1 0 2 { 'set'
test
   $ 2 1 0 2
4
   $ 'test'
4
```

The dimensions of the result is equal to the dimensions of `x` plus the dimensions of the *items* of `y`. So, if you have a two-dimensional `x` taking two-dimensional *items* from a three-dimensional `y`, you will have a four-dimensional result:

```
   (2 2 $ 1 1 0 1) { i. 5 3 4
12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23

12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23


 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11

12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23
   $ (2 2 $ 1 1 0 1) { i. 5 3 4
2 2 3 4
```

One final note: the monadic Ravel (`,`) will reduce the result to a list (one-dimensional array).

```
   , 0 1 { 2 3 $ 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
   , i. 2 2 2 2
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: Thanks Dane, this is an explanation that makes it for me.

Answer (score 2):

From (`{`) selects the items of a noun. For  `2 3 $ 1 2 3 4 5 6` the items are the two rows because items are the components that make up the noun.

```
   [ a=. 2 3 $ 1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3
4 5 1
   0 { a
1 2 3
```

If you just had `1 2 3` then the items would be the individual atoms.

```
   [ b=. 1 2 3
1 2 3
   0 { b
1
```

If you used `1 3 $ 1 2 3`  then there is only one item and the result would be

```
   [ c=. 1 3 $ 1 2 3
1 2 3
   0 { c
1 2 3
```

The number of items can be found with Tally (`#`), and is the lead dimension of the Shape (`$`) of the noun.

```
   $ a
2 3
   $ b
3
   $ c
1 3

   # a
2
   # b
3
   # c
1
```